# Having issues with updating Node.js

Tags: node.js

I am currently trying to update node to a current version. I have tried downloading and installing from the nodejs.org directly and I have also tried

> brew upgrade node

and also

> npm install -g n
>
> npm cache clean -f
>
> sudo n stable
>
> npm update -g

Even after all that when I run "node -v", I still get my old version. It looks like when i run npm install -g n, it installs the old version instead of the new version.

Please help me update my node.

Comment: What OS system are you using? Are you already tried uninstall the node of your sistem? Looks like you have double installed it.

Comment: try nvm for upgrade

Comment: If you have install `n` , why not you do so ?  `sudo n 6.2.0`  where 6.2.0 is version which you want to install.

Comment: I am using mac OS.

Comment: i didn't realize i had nvm. I just used
> npm use v8.9.1